# Using 2D Lidar SLAM and Build Path to the controller

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

I have a 2D Lidar laser scanner(Sick TiM-561) works on the ubuntu 14.04LTS with ROS jade PC, and I have a computer
which is [embedded program controller for the vehicle](http://www.terasoft.com.tw/english/htm/pd-mbox1.html).
Now I want to use Lidar to scan the environment and use ROS PC to **build the map** and then **build a path** to feed the embedded program controller to control the steering wheel for following the path.

So here I need to mapping and a path signal for the controller, and then the controller just follow the path to the goal place.

My case is when Lidar scans a parallel parking space and ROS PC build a map, then if I want to pull my car into that
parking space, the ROS will build a path for the controller to track it.

I saw this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) but this is for the specified robot of ROS, but the robot which I want to contnot a ROS robot.  Could someone can give me some directions? Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223515/using-2d-lidar-slam-and-build-path-to-the-controller/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Tim has an Ethernet Interface so you can communicate direct with the Sensor from the ROS PC.

So Ros Can Generatate the Map.

The you need a Kinematic description of you vehicle (Differentialdrive, Akermann, Mecanum, Omi...):

Asume you have an :
And now Is you Turn to Code: For the Embedded PC you write a simple Programm which sends the Encoder values and receives wheel velocities comands.

On the Ros PC you program the counterpart ROS-Node (Read Encode Write Position) and with the  Kinematic description you can Publish ["Odom MSGs"](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) and Subscribe the ["cmd_val"](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html)  Topic and send the content to your Embedded PC

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1